# extracting text from online pdf file (sharepoint)

Tags: c#, pdf, sharepoint, text, extract

I know similar questions has been asked and answered, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem. 
So basically I would like to extract text from an online pdf file using C#, which I could achieve with [itextsharp] library. However this works with some random pdf files I could find by searching them on google. My goal would be to do the same with a private sharepoint account, where several PDF files are stored. My chrome web browser is set to remember the user and the password, but I still couldn't achieve it with my code. For me it seems there is no problem with the authentication, but I might be wrong. Here is the code:

```
public static string pdfTX(string path)
{
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);

    request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

    request.UserAgent = @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36";
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    //  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(uName, pWord);

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();

    string textPDF = string.Empty;

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(stream); //error here (iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: 'PDF header signature not found.')

    for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
    {
       textPDF += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);
    }

    reader.Close();
    response.Close();
    //  readStream.Close();
    // public string passtext = text;

    return textPDF;
}
```

I would be glad for any kind of help or information!
Thank you for your time and effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my test code with CSOM(I faced same error if I use stream to read the file).

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string login = "lee@domain.onmicrosoft.com"; //give your username here  

            using (var context = new ClientContext("https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/tst"))
            {
                string password = "pw";
                SecureString sec_pass = new SecureString();
                Array.ForEach(password.ToArray(), sec_pass.AppendChar);
                sec_pass.MakeReadOnly();
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, sec_pass);

                var path = "/sites/tst/mydoc3/beginning_sharepoint_2013_development.pdf";
                var file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(path);
                context.Load(file);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                ClientResult<System.IO.Stream> data = file.OpenBinaryStream();
                context.Load(file);
                context.ExecuteQuery();                

                string textPDF = string.Empty;
                using (System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
                {
                    if (data != null)
                    {
                        data.Value.CopyTo(mStream);
                        byte[] array = mStream.ToArray();
                        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(array);

                        for (int page = 1; page <= reader.NumberOfPages; page++)
                        {
                            textPDF += PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, page);
                        }

                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }
            }            
            Console.WriteLine("done");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
I accepted your answer as solution, however if you or anybody else could give any information about why

context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

instead of

 context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, sec_pass);

doesn't work. I would be glad for that too!
Thanks again.